# Como setar valores no Enum?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Observem a Grid

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O registro que está vindo do banco de dados é de uma classe Enum, o correto era para o resultado na grid fosse imprimida nome Valor e não V.

Esse é o Enum;

```
  VALOR("V", "Valor"),
    PERCENTUAL("P", "Percentual"),
    DIA("D", "Dia"),
    HORA("H", "Hora");
```

Eu prefiro tratar esse problema Back-End invés que no Front-End, a classe enum está criada como mostra abaixo porque ela também será carregada em outra partes do sistema como listBox, minha ideia seria quando o valor vier como V fosse setado automaticamente como Valor, quando vier P fosse setado automaticamente como Percentual e assim por diante.

```
public enum EventoTipoMultiplicador implements EnumConverter<EventoTipoMultiplicador, String> {

    VALOR("V", "Valor"),
    PERCENTUAL("P", "Percentual"),
    DIA("D", "Dia"),
    HORA("H", "Hora");

    private final String codigo;
    private final String descricao;

    public static final EnumValues<EventoTipoMultiplicador, String> VALORES = EnumUtils
            .getEnumValuesMap(EventoTipoMultiplicador.class);

    EventoTipoMultiplicador(String codigo, String descricao) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }



    @JsonCreator
    public static EventoTipoMultiplicador fromValue(String v) {
        return EventoTipoMultiplicador.VALORES.getEnum(v);
    }

}
```

Essas alterações podem serem feitas aqui nesse método abaixo;

```
   @JsonCreator
    public static EventoTipoMultiplicador fromValue(String v) {
        return EventoTipoMultiplicador.VALORES.getEnum(v);
    }
```

Ao carregar a GRID ele apresenta o seguinte resultado com o debug do STS.

O problema é que não sei como fazer alteração no método por falta de experiência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você só quer retornar a descrição do enum?

Comment: Eu preciso retorna a descrição e o código.

Answer (score 1):

```
return EventoTipoMultiplicador.VALORES.getEnum(v).getDescricao();
```

**OU**

Altere o `toString()` do enumerado para dar `return` do atributo `descricao`.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return descricao;
    }
```

E quando quiser buscar a descrição faça simplesmente `enumerado.toString()`